# How to extract Hours from the date time format 12/10/2012 12:18:58 PM?

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

How do I extract the hours from the date time format `12/10/2012  12:18:58 PM`?

I found this `Hour(Format(d1, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss HH24"))` on another Stack Overflow question, but not working for me.

Comment: Although you have some solid answers, your questions was not very well written.  "doesn't work" tells us nothing.  Please consider explaining exactly what isn't working.  Also, if you are referencing another Stack Overflow question, it is useful to provide a link to the question so we can see the context that the other answer was offered.

Answer (score 11):

This should work

=TEXT(D1, "hh")

and format as time

Answer (score 3):

If `D1` contains a Date/Time as `Date Time Serial Number` or as a string recognisable as a `date time` then use `=Hour(D1)`

Eg `D1` = the string `21/03/2013 18:45:00`  `=Hour(D1)` = `18`

Eg `D1` = `41354.781250`  then `=Hour(D1)` = `18`
Note: `D1` may contain a value but be formatted to display as a date/time.  Check the cell number format.

To do this in VBA try this

```
Sub demo()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Hr As Long

    Set rng = Range("D1")

    Hr = Hour(rng.Value)

    Debug.Print Hr
End Sub
```

View the result in the `Immediate Window`

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
Hour(format(now(), "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 1):

if "12/10/2012 12:18:58 PM" is in cell A1:

```
=TIME(HOUR(a1),MINUTE(a1),SECOND(a1))
```

After the formula is entered, you can right click on "format cells" and select the time format you want to see.  I've verified this formula in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/date-time-functions-visual-basic
it really work in vba

Or just use `Now` if you want the date and time by now